# Closed subspace of Hilbertspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a norm closed subspace of a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$. Is it true that if $x_n \in X$ converges weakly to $x \in \mathcal H$, then also $x \in X$ ?

Comment: By "subspace" do you mean a linear subspace?

Comment: Yes, indeed a linear subspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Let $Y=X^\perp.$ Then for every $y\in Y$ we have $\langle x,y\rangle=\lim_{n\to\infty} \langle x_n,y\rangle=0.$ Hence $x\in Y^\perp=X.$

Comment: Note that a more general statement is also true: a convex subset of a Banach space is closed if and only if it is weakly closed.